# Android Mp3 play from url

Tags: android, media-player, mp3

How do I run the following tutorial using an online mp3 url? I tried replacing the url but it doesn't seem to be working. I want to use the same code but with the url. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The tutorial linke: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm
The mp3 url is: http://searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How to play an .mp3 from the /raw folder:

Download the .mp3 file, save it to song.mp3 and paste into the /raw folder.
If you don´t have /raw folder, just create it into the /res folder.

[image]

this example doesn´t load the .mp3 from internet, play the .mp3 from the resources.

```
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

### How to **`play an .mp3 from the url:`**,

change the `oncreate()` method of the example to:

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_video);
      songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      songName.setText("song.mp3");    
    //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
      Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3");      
      try {
          mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
          mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);
          mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          mediaPlayer.prepare(); //don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
          mediaPlayer.start();
       } catch (IOException e) {           
          e.printStackTrace();
      }                  
      seekbar.setClickable(false);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);

   }
```

so you will able to play the audio mp3 from the url  specified.

don´t forget to add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

into your Manifest.xml

Comment: I am sorry but I meant I need to play file from url not downloaded file. I already am able to do that but since I have so many files and downloading them will increase the size, I need to use a way to use url.

Comment: do you have this permission?    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: OMG!!! PERFECT!! It's finally working now. Thank you so much for the solution. :D

Comment: @Elenasys How can I play 2 songs from 2 URLs one after the other?

Comment: You must in fact use prepareAsync() if the mp3 comes from the internet, otherwise you'd lock your marvellous UI thread for a number of seconds. It's OK to call prepare for local files, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Through URL**

```
    try {
        String url = "http://www.all-birds.com/Sound/western%20bluebird.wav"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Through res ---> inside --> row Folder**

```
MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.genuine_);
mp2.start();
```

Comment: `setAudioStreamType` is deprecated

Comment: I did it in the following way:                                                                                 
 `mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
.build())
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicURL)
mediaPlayer.prepare()
mediaPlayer.start()`