# I can not play music with Dropbox link.(Android applications.)

Tags: android

I want to try to play a direct link from the Dropbox app but do not make success.

```
Uri myUri = Uri
            .parse("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/LieuTraiTieuThuy2006Tap5.mp3?_subject_uid=442310434&w=AAB7e-MLX5QBBdqbf0EXNmTv5NkX-hRJBWtjv5Vv9dryRw");
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this link is successful.
http://searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3

I found this link in this topic.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343389/android-mp3-play-from-url)

I just wanted to use DropBox to store my music later. So you can explain why my DropBox Link does not work in this application.

Comment: What do you mean by "do not make success"? Please be more specific.

Comment: I will compare two such cases:
Case 1:                                                                                                Uri myUri = Uri
            .parse("http://searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3");
Success. 
Case 2:                                                                                                        Uri myUri = Uri
            .parse("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/LieuTraiTieuThuy2006Tap5.mp3?_subject_uid=442310434&w=AAB7e-MLX5QBBdqbf0EXNmTv5NkX-hRJBWtjv5Vv9dryRw");                                                                                
Unsuccessful.

Comment: Did u get this working?